# git ignore subfolder except .txt files

Tags: git

I have a subfolder `data` containing 3 subfolders, each has both `.json` and `.txt` files.

 adding

```
/**/data/*
!data/**/*.txt
```

didn't work, and I still don't see the txt files in the untracked files like I expect to

Comment: Have these files already been *added* before you decided to make git ignore them? (at any point) Because if so, patterns aren't your problem.

Comment: I believe you'll have to un-ignore files in each subdirectory explicitly. Please see the linked duplicate.